# SQL COUNT items that meet and do not meet WHERE condition when applying a LIMIT (on AWS SELECT)

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, count, where-clause, limit

I have a SQL question.

I have a table with a list of rows of format [user:String, score:Double]

I would like to COUNT the number of items (number of users) in my table where the score > xx (input that I specify). I need to use LIMIT as I use AWS select on a boto3 lambda function (there is a max memory). I would like to know how many items have been scanned to reach this limit.

For example, if I LIMIT to 1000, maybe I will need to scan 3000 items, 2000 items will be < xx and 1000 items (the limit) will be > xx so I get a feel that my user will be in the top 33% (arguable I know as it depends if the subset is representative etc :) )

How to do it (and how to do it on AWS select, as there are some functions that are not available like "order by" etc)?

**EDIT**: To add details, see the following picture.

[image]

I can run `select count(*) FROM s3object[*][*] s where s.score>14 limit 5`
and I will get 1 row ok.

**Now, if I have 1 million users**, and I have to limit the results to 1000 (because of memory). How I do I know how many items where scanned to get to these 1000 rows ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: The limit makes no sense whatsoever.  The query returns one row.

Comment: @gordon Ha, so it does not apply the LIMIT first, then apply the count ? In my case, if the limit of items is reached of 1000 items, I was expecting count to say 1000
Also do you know what amount of memory is consumed if I scan the whole table to count the number of items > input score? This was my point of limiting the number of rows scanned

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to COUNT the number of items (number of users) in my table where the score > xx (input that I specify).

Isn't the query you want a simple aggregation query with a filter?

```
select count(*)
from t
where score > ?;
```

`?` is a parameter with the limit that you specify.  This always returns one row, so there is no need for `LIMIT`.

Comment: gordon, I have added more details, I hope it makes sense!